# Как указывать рамеры согластно Material design

Tags: android, material-design

Согласно `Material design` при любой плотности пикселей (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, ...) и размеров экранов `view` должны занимать определенное количество dp? То есть на устройстве xhdpi 1dp = 2px, xxhdpi = 1dp = 3px,... и что все `view` в `dp` не должны растягиваться относительно соотношения сторон? Или все `view` должны растягиваться, то есть для разных экранов, должны быть разные размеры в `dp`?

Comment: определенное количество dp - расстояния между View. Cами View, как правило, имеют динамические размеры, которые подстраиваются под размеры экрана. для View не указываются размеры в dp в абсолютном большинстве случаев. [Гайдлайны](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо. Буду искать точечно источник этой информации

Comment: Я раньше много уже писал по верстке в андроид, посмотрите в моих ответах. Другие участники конечно тоже. Вообще тема здесь уже достаточно раскрыта.

Answer (score 0):

Естественно на разных размерах экранов размеры элементов в dp могут отличаться.

Сохранять желательно(!) соотношения сторон. Т.е. если у вас плашка 10 к 3, то желательно(!) выдерживать это отношение на всех девайсах. Почему желательно? Потому, что экраны тоже имеют разные соотношения сторон и на, например, квадратном и прямоугольных экранах один и тот же элемент будет смотреться совсем по разному.

Тут больше стоит заморачиваться общей сеткой и отступами между элементами.